# Ford-Fulkerson and one example, verifying need

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree

If we have the following graph:

[image]

Suppose I need to show one by one increasing in final flow (X>1).

1. if I choose S-C-B-A-D-T then because of B-A we can pass just one flow. after that B-A capacity is equal to zero and we can use it as a edge of reverse direction and add it's capacity to 1.
2. Then if I choose S-A-B-T one another flow add to final flow and then the reverse edge can be used again and capacity of this edge is 0.
3. we can again use  S-C-B-A-D-T and add one flow to final flow and then edge B-A reversed and capacity of it be zero.

this steps with other edge selections combination can be repeat until max flow is reached.

I need anyone verify are these three steps correct? my understanding of [Ford-Fulkerson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm).

Comment: There's absolutely nothing in the question making it a C++ question so I suggest replacing the C++ tag with the [tag:ford-fulkerson] tag that you just removed.

Comment: @TedLyngmo seems right. thannks

Comment: You are correct; Ford-Fulkerson does not specify an ordering in which to iterate through the augmenting paths of the residual network, which is why you can pick and choose paths as you please.

Comment: Would you please post answer @EvilTak? about reversing edge is correct?